# What does "Five times over!" mean here?

Tags: meaning

I came across a sentence while reading Newspaper and I'm wondering what does the sentence mean in this context.  This news article completed with the sentence `Five times over!`.  What does it mean actually here?

**Excerpt from the Newspaper:**

> Here’s introducing iDiva: Five
>   Magazines in One that packs in the
>   best of five of India’s top women’s
>   magazines in a single new weekly.
>   . . .
>   . . .
>   . . .
>   A magazine that gives you all this and
>   more should cost the earth, right?
>   Luckily this one doesn’t. At an
>   introductory price of Rs 5 per copy,
>   we are sure you’ll find it a steal.
>   **Five times over!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick to understanding this advert comes at the beginning:

> Here’s introducing iDiva: Five Magazines in One

So the publisher is saying their magazine is the equivalent of five other magazines.

Also they are selling the first issue at a cut down introductory price:

> At an introductory price of Rs 5 per copy

So, in their mind, the magazine is cheap even compared to a normal magazine, but because it is five magazines in one, the cheapness is exaggerated by that multiple, so this deal is five times better than any normal discount on a magazine, i.e. *five times over*.

Answer (score 5):

The term "X times over" was originally used in the context of recouping an investment; the speaker is saying that someone who pays something will be repaid five times their original investment. It was originally seen very closely tied to finance; an investment fund, stock deal, or a business expansion or retooling. It is still most often used in terms of money, no matter how loosely, but the usage has become quite wide; the user may never see a dime of their investment returned in cash, but the promise is they will receive some tangible or intangible benefit that they would consider to be worth several times what they paid.

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand the thing completely.

> ...we are sure you’ll find it a steal.

*Steal* refers to a bargain that's so good, and so cheap, it's *almost* like you stole something. It's so cheap, it's like paying nothing, and still getting the thing.

*"Five times over"* refers to the fact that they are sure that not only will you "find it a steal", but five times as good as a steal. That's what "five times over" here means.